# show the image with specific named using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, imagesource

I have some picture in folder "../../images"

I give the name of picture with example

101_2018_1_1.jpg

101_2018_1_2.jpg

101_2018_1_3.jpg

101 is on var1

2018 is on id year

and 1 is on var3

and the last is auto increment

how can I call all the images with specific named based on combo box I chose with javascript and show the image on my page?

here the example of my form

```html
<form>
<select name="var1" id="var1" >
 <option value='101'>id 1</option>
 <option value='102'>id 2</option>
 <option value='103'>id 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text"  id="year" name="year" value="<?php echo date('Y'); ?>">

<select name="var3" id="var3" >
 <option value='1'>case 1</option>
 <option value='2'>case 2</option>
 <option value='3'>case 3</option>
 <option value='4'>case 4</option>
</select>

<button  type="submit" name="search">search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there fix number of photos on *auto increment* variable?

Comment: one number last is auto increment variable, but i just need to catch 101_2018_1 , the last number we can ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `jQuery` you can do something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var URL = "www.example.com/image/";

    //Get the values of form element 
    var var1 = $("#var1").val();
    var year = $("#year").val();
    var var3 = $("#var3").val();

    //Check Up to 10 increments
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      var img = URL + var1 + "_" + year + "_" + var3 + "_" + i + ".jpg";
      getImage(img);
    }

    return false;
  });
});

/*
  Check if image exist and add it.
  If not, just console
*/
function getImage(image_url) {
  $.get(image_url)
    .done(function() {
      // Image does exist - append on #image-container container
      $("#image-container").append('<img src="' + image_url + '">');
    }).fail(function() {
      // Image doesn't exist - do nothing.
      console.log(image_url + " does not exist.");
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="var1" id="var1">
    <option value='101'>id 1</option>
    <option value='102'>id 2</option>
    <option value='103'>id 3</option>
   </select>

  <input type="text" id="year" name="year" value="2018">

  <select name="var3" id="var3">
    <option value='1'>case 1</option>
    <option value='2'>case 2</option>
    <option value='3'>case 3</option>
    <option value='4'>case 4</option>
  </select>

  <div id="image-container"> </div>

  <button type="submit" name="search">search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would do something like:

```js
var imgUrl, counter = 3;
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', function() {
  imgUrl = "../../" + document.getElementById('var1').value + "_" + document.getElementById('year').value + "_" + document.getElementById('var3').value + "_";
  alert(imgUrl);
  for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    var url = imgUrl + i.toString() + ".jpg"
    //img.setAttribute('src', );
    alert(url);
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="var1" id="var1">
    <option value='101'>id 1</option>
    <option value='102'>id 2</option>
    <option value='103'>id 3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="year" name="year" value="<?php echo date('Y'); ?>">

  <select name="var3" id="var3">
    <option value='1'>case 1</option>
    <option value='2'>case 2</option>
    <option value='3'>case 3</option>
    <option value='4'>case 4</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" name="search" id='search'>
</form>
```

That would get you the image url, set the src attribute to that url, then append it to the body.